# HTML Script To Check Website Status

Tags: html

Is there a way to make a HTML script to check a website every 5 minutes to see if it's offline or not and if it is make a file with the time and date.

Comment: Please use correct spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with HTML. HTML just allows you to present your data in a better way.

The best way to do this is server side scripting using nodejs, cron job with PHP, python, etc.

You can also consider third party services like uptime robot(https://uptimerobot.com/) and pingdom (https://www.pingdom.com/)

Someone may think that this can be done using Javascript in side HTML, but to write on file you need server side script.

Comment: I have tried the third party like uptime robot but does not work like I would like it to. So What Would be the best solution for this then?

Comment: The best way to do this is server side scripting using nodejs, cron job with PHP, python, etc.

Comment: How would I do that as I don't really know those languages?

Comment: Please consider upvoting and approving the answer.